# Convergence in sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

in $\mathbb{R^2} $ $(a_n, b_n)\rightarrow(a, b) \Leftrightarrow a_n\rightarrow a, b_n \rightarrow b$

Show that in $d_2$.

How can I show that?

Comment: What do you define by $d_2$?

Comment: I guess $d_2$ is an arbitrary complete metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: $d_2$ : $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$  $(x, y) \mapsto d_{2}(x,y)=((x_{1}-y_{1})^2 + (x_{2}-y_{2})^2)^{1/2}$ @nicomezi

Comment: It should be in the question

Comment: Could you please edit the question with the definition of $d_2$?

Answer (score 2):

Try to show that, for $N_2$ your norm in $\mathbb R^2$ and $N_1$ your norm in $\mathbb R$, there is a constant $C$ such that
$$C^{-1}(N_1(a) + N_1(b)) \le N_2((a,b)) \le C(N_1(a) + N_1(b))$$
and use that to show the equivalence.